# Passing values from a page to another page in HTML mobile app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've made users to enter some values in a `html` page:
Here is the code:

```
$(function() {
            $("#savesymptoms").bind(
                    "click",
                    function() {
                        var url = "notes.html?acne="
                                + encodeURIComponent($("#acne").val())
                                + "&back="
                                + encodeURIComponent($("#bloat").val());
                        window.location.href = url;
                    });
        });
```

And I've added an alert like this:
`alert("values passed");`
But I'm not sure that this is working. I've got some 10 values to pass to another page. Above code contains only two values. Can I use arrays to pass all 10 values? I don't want to use nomenclature used in my code, i.e., individual value passing.
P.S: `acne` and `bloat` are the ids of the fields where user enters the data. `notes.html` is the page where I want to pass the data.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can use `sessionStorage` in `HTML5`

For setting a value

```
sessionStorage.setItem('name', 'value');
```

For getting the value:

```
sessionStorage.getItem('name');
```

if you want to store the value permanently use localStorage.

Since you have almost 10 values push all those values in a JSON and store it either in sessionStorage/localStorage.
You can retrieve it else where and use as per your wish

Note:values stored will be in the form of string even if you push it as JSON.You will have to make it to JSON using `Jquery` functions

**Alternative**

You can store it as  `window.name`
But this will be only valid till the window lasts/tab closed(same as sessionStorage)

Comment: This is good one, but I just want to pass the data from a page to `notes.html` page. After passing the data to `notes.html`, I'll save it in localstorage.

Comment: I want to pass the data as shown in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter. My plan is to store the values after passing the data, `not storing and passing`